# Cannot get radio button value on while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am doing a simple quiz program using PHP and JavaScript(for its timer)

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#CCFFCC">

<?php
session_start ();

$_SESSION['username'];
?>

<div id="wrap">

<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="table"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="q_quiz"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['q_id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE q_id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" frame="box" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#CCFFCC"><h3>Quiz Info : </h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#CCFFCC"><strong>Quiz Name : </strong><?php echo  $rows['q_name']; ?></td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div style="font-weight: bold" id="quiz-time-left"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var max_time = <?php echo $rows['q_time'] ?>;
var c_seconds  = 0;
var total_seconds =60*max_time;
max_time = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds';
function init(){
document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds';
setTimeout("CheckTime()",999);
}
function CheckTime(){
document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds' ;
if(total_seconds <=0){
setTimeout('document.quiz.submit()',1);

} else
{
total_seconds = total_seconds -1;
max_time = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
setTimeout("CheckTime()",999);
}

}
init();
</script>
</font>
```

Problem starts here

```
<br>
<?php
//so i will set a default score of 0.
$score = 0;
$tbl_name2="a_quiz";
$sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE q_id='$id'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
?>

<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr style='overflow:hidden; word-wrap:break-word;'>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>Question:</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen" style="max-width: 1000px;"><?php echo $rows['q_question'] ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>A</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo  $rows['q_question'] ?>" value="a"><?php echo $rows['a'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>B</strong></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td width="77%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows['q_question'] ?>" value="b"><?php echo $rows['b'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>C</strong></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td width="77%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows['q_question'] ?>" value="c"><?php echo $rows['c'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>D</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows['q_question'] ?>" value="d"><?php echo $rows['d'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
```

In this part im getting the correct answer in the database (the answer is a)
    $correct_answer == $rows['answer'];

This score = score + 1; is not working

```
if ($correct_answer==$_POST[$rows['q_question']]){
$score = $score + 1;
}




?>
<?php

$connection=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
mysql_select_db('thesis');

$username= $_SESSION['username'];


$query6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE username='$username'");
$row6 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query6);
$s_id = $row6['id'];
$name = $row6['name'];
$email = $row6['email'];
$position = $row6['position'];
?>
```

This is where I get all the data needed in the results

```
<p hidden>
<input type="text" name="s_id" value="<?php echo $s_id ?>">
<input type="text" name="q_id" value="<?php echo $rows['q_id'];?>">
<input type="text" name="score" value="<?php echo $score; ?>">
</p>
</table></td>
</tr>
<hr>
</table><br>
<?php
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Answer" class="btn">
</form>
```

After hitting the submit button, im only getting s_id, q_id , but the score is still 0 even if I selected the correct answer

My problem here is getting the selected radio button and then comparing it to the answer(where is in the database)

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick mock up and this worked for me.

```
$answer = $_POST["'" . $rows['q_question'] . "'"];

if ($correct_answer == $answer)
{
    $score++;
}
```

Comment: its says undefined index in the line of Notice: Undefined index: 'wwwww' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis System\student\take_quiz.php on line 167

Comment: Is it possible anywhere in your script or database, it contains 'wwwww'?

Comment: i have solved my crazy problem, i only need to get the post in the other php file and it worked